# How to make Google Chrome not to check system clock or certificates at all?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, internet, certificate, clock

How to make Google Chrome not to check system clock? I want to switch back my system clock and still can access to gmail etc.

Comment: I need a bit more info... what do you mean by not check the system clock.. you mean read the time at all? Chrome, like many apps, uses the clock for a wide variety of things. Preventing that would break many things in Chrome. What do you want to do that you need to change the clock?

Comment: @Ram I need 3 days more on my Visual Studio 2013 Pre Realease student license I've got to finish thesis and I have no time for free 'upgrade' and reinstall everything, it would take many hours with all additional stuff I use in the thesis, there is just to many things to go wrong, I can reinstall once I finish it all. When I set the system clock time back chrome doesn't let me use gmail and google search because of the certificate is not valid yet.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer is to buy the product you use. Things might be different for students depending on country/age etc - I don't know your situation so won't won't address it.

Set the date to Jan 17th and you should be fine from a certificate perspective at gmail and google; both certs are valid from Jan 15 - May 14 so you should be able to keep pushing it back to late Jan until they replace their certificate, probably in early May.

Another solution is to use a proxy server that does all the SSL stuff for you while ignoring all the SSL errors that would normally protect you from giving away your bank account 'reset your password' link.

Comment: Thank you. The license is free, but I am forced to switch to final product.

I switched the data to January but still it does not let me to do so. Is there any fast way to set proxy... networking is not my speciality? Thank you for answer.

Comment: What do you mean it does not let you do so? Chrome won't connect go gmail - what error message is given? I don't know a good and easy way to get a proxy setup for you here - bad and not that hard or not that bad and harder :(